# Possible approaches to the Ship City problem?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, combinatorics

About few ago in my freshman year of college I stumbled across an [an old blog post](https://veniamin-ilmer.github.io/ship-city) on r/programming posing a programming challenge. Here is the short version of it:

> Hundreds of ships would like to dock to each other to build a floating city of ships.
>
> Although they are all bound to each other, any ship must be able to
> leave the collective without needing to ask any other ship to move.
>
> This means they always need to have a route to get to open waters.
>
> However to maintain physical stability against the waters, there
> should be a route to be able to walk from one ship to any other ship.
>
> Given a n x n size of the city, what is the most compact tiling possible for all of the ships?

He provides some good examples in the blog post which clear up what the target is. I wanted to take another shot at the problem but it still seems insanely hard. I have done a lot of searching but I haven't found anything else about this problem. The author says he failed to solve it mathematically, and I also can't imagine a mathematical solution/model to this outside of combinatorics. A brute force approach would be out of the question due to how fast-growing the number of possible configuration is.  What potential approaches do you think would be worth considering?

Comment: Have you tried using a SAT solver?

Comment: @D.W. I haven't considered this but I guess that could be a good approach. I'm assuming that using a SAT solver would require representing the problem as a boolean formula in CNF?

Comment: Yes. The primary challenge is to represent "you can walk from ship A to ship B" in CNF, and to represent "ship A has a route to open waters" in CNF.  This is basically a transitive reachability expression, similar to transitive reachability on a graph, and can probably be expressed in the same way.  I suggest spending some time thinking about how to formulate that, and if you get stuck, show what you've come up with so far and what aspect you are having difficulty representing in CNF.

Comment: The problem seems underspecified. The blog post seems to assume an n x n grid. Then, on the n x n grid, pick points (ships) such that 1) all ships are connected (on the grid via a path of adjacent ships) 2) all ships are adjacent to the outside and 3) the result is as compact as possible. I *think* 3 means: given the number of ships, the number of enclosed non-ships is as low as possible. But there must be another condition on placement, or "place 1 ship somewhere" will always be a valid solution. What is that condition? Do we need to place as many ships as possible? The author doesn't say.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very systemmatic approach to solve the problem but it depends on my instinct and it has no direct proof yet (or I am not sure if it is "correct"). Maybe someone else can prove/disprove my approach.

First, I will not try to put 100 ships into a square as the question asks but I will try to find the maximum number of ships can be put inside a `nxn` square, which will eventually lead to the answer of the original question.

My instinct says to create corridors(1 space between) to get to the maximum efficiency. Like a parking lot for ships. For example:

```
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
<> <> <> <> <> <...
<> <> <> <> <> <...
<> <> <> <> <> <...
<> <> <> <> <> <...
<> <> <> <> <> <...
<> <> <> <> <> <...
<> <> <> <> <> <...
...................
...................
...................
```

Of course we cover top and left part first and then create corridors. However, this method relies on inside being divisible by 3. Let's consider other sizes (remainder 1 and 2).

If we have remainder 1 inside (`(n-1)/3` gives remainder 1), it is simple, like below:

```
^^^^^^^^^^^
<> <> <> <>
<> <> <> <>
<> <> <> <>
<> <> <> <>
<> <> <> <>
<> <> <> <>
<> <> <> <>
<> <> <> <>
<> <> <> <>
<> <> <> <>
```

If we have remainder 2 inside, it is a bit more complicated. I tried this part manually and I am not sure, but came up with the following in the end:

```
^^^^^^^^^
<> <> <
<> <> <
<> <> <
<> <> <
<> <> <
<> <> <
<> <> <
<> <> <
```

We have `2xn-1` space left. After a couple tries, I realized that I can create corridors here too, but horizontally:

```
^^^^^^^^^
<> <> <vv
<> <> <
<> <> <^^
<> <> <vv
<> <> <
<> <> <^^
<> <> <vv
<> <> <>
```

To formulize my approach to get the number of maximum ships inside `nxn` size square, I came up with the following:

(remainder 2 inside) For n = 3k, $2n + 1 + \frac{n-3}{3} * 2 * (n-1) + \frac{n-3}{3} * 2 * 2 + 1$

(remainder 0 inside) For n = 3k + 1, $2n + 1 + \frac{n-1}{3} * 2 * (n-1)$

(remainder 1 inside) For n = 3k + 2, $2n + 1 + \frac{n-2}{3} * 2 * (n-1) + n - 1$

These formulas might be reduced into one formula with floor and ceil functions but I didn't have time for it. I might look into it later.

Furthermore, these formulas might not work for small n. I am not sure about the base case.

To get the answer for 100 ships, we just need to increase n until it becomes bigger than 100. So it should be $n = 12$, the city can hold 104 ships.

Comment: Haven't checked in on this post in a while. This looks good, have you tried to see if your approach can produce the optimal solutions for n=3 and n=4 from the blog? That would probably be worth trying. I'm also working on brute-forcing solutions for n>4 at the moment so maybe that will show some kind of pattern similar to what you're doing.